# How to properly fix contacts in SpriteKit?

Tags: xcode, ios7, sprite-kit

I use this code and it has to work, but it doesn't:

```
static const uint32_t platformCategory  =  0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t playerCategory  =  0x1 << 2;
```

Code of player:

```
self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
self.player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.player.size];
self.player.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
self.player.physicsBody.friction = 0;
self.player.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true;
self.player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
self.player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = platformCategory;
self.player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = platformCategory;
[self addChild:self.player];
```

And code of "platforms":

```
- (void)addPlatformRight {

  int plType = arc4random()%3;

  SKSpriteNode * platform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString      stringWithFormat:@"platform%d", plType]];
  platform.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+100, self.frame.size.height-200);
  platform.size = CGSizeMake(platform.size.width*1.2, platform.size.height*2);
  platform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:platform.size];
  platform.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
  platform.physicsBody.friction = 0;
  platform.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true;
  platform.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = platformCategory;
  platform.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
  platform.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory;

  [self addChild:platform];
  [platform runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI/4.0*8 duration:3], [SKAction removeFromParent]]]];
}
```

And

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  NSLog(@"contact");
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two overlapping non-dynamic bodies do not generate contact events, at least one of them has to be dynamic